# Send a message when your question is closed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, closed-questions, global-inbox

I recently added [a question to the Sci-Fi site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4027/are-the-third-and-fourth-book-of-space-oddysey-turned-into-movies), unfortunately this question was closed because I could have looked it up quite easily.

However that is not my point, normally when there is interaction on your question you will get a notifier any sites header under the 'inbox'.  This does not happen when your question is closed.  That means that I won't be educated about the etiquette required from this (a special) site and continue with bad questions.

I would ask for the feature, that upon being closed of your question, you would receive a message about this in your general SE inbox.

Comment: Post authors and followers now receive inbox notificaitons on [close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356742/question-closed-notifications-experiment-results-and-graduation) events.