# Notification on close

Tags: feature-request, bug, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send a message when your question is closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94390/send-a-message-when-your-question-is-closed)

Shouldn't there be a 'your question got closed' notification? If there is, it's not working(i fuzzily recall such a notification, but that may have been for migration).

I asked a question on programmers.SE: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/140027/good-practice-and-terminology-of-braces

It got closed (duplicate). Now, I live on physics.SE, so I never got any notification that the question was closed.

Is this a bug, or an intentional feature?

Comment: I've never seen a question closed without at least one comment, which appear in your global inbox. That being said, no - there's no special notification for closure. Having a 'Closed' message delivered to the inbox may not be a bad idea, especially if trusted users vote to delete it quickly.

Comment: @TimPost you will now--check out the linked post. The only reason I found out was that I was bored and decided to check out other questions on programmers.SE

Comment: Umm, btw, this was closed (exact duplicate of another feature request)

Comment: @TimPost yeah, either inbox or make a dropdown like the new badges/migration notification

Comment: Yeah, that one went into the night with crickets chirping.

Comment: I think inbox would be best, since you'd get notified even if you were on another site.

Comment: @TimPost hmm.. But that question gives some points against it.. Which IMO are pretty flat... It could be opt-in or something..

Comment: @TimPost alright, wrote my answer to that question http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125882/178438 The reasons JeffAtwood gave IMO are unjustified...