# Why doesn't Stack Exchange have a notification center in account preferences with toggle option?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, global-inbox, top-bar, notification-bar

After reading lots and lots of questions on Meta about notifications... there could be one solution for all the questions about notifications on here! Just have a notification toggle center! Facebook has one and it works great, if someone doesn't want to receive a certain notification, they don't have to... but at least the user can decided what they want to be notified about and what they don't.

I think a power user and a regular user have different notification needs, and the site should reflect these needs based on user opt-in and out.

I'm not talking about email notification, I'm taking about in-site notifications.

- [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor)
- [Deletion notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116686/deletion-notifications)
- [Mark questions to receive notifications and updates?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/mark-questions-to-receive-notifications-and-updates)
- [Notification for voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136530/notification-for-voting)
- [Optional notification on an edit to an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97740/optional-notification-on-an-edit-to-an-answer)
- [Notification on close](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125873/notification-on-close)
- [Question Deletion Notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/question-deletion-notification)
- [Comment deletion notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117854/comment-deletion-notification)
- The list can go on forever!

Attached is a screen shot from Facebook's Notifications Preferences (obviously Stack Exchange would have different preferences):

[image: Facebook Notification Preferences]

Comment: The problem is different: "bad" notifications (e.g. "your post was deleted") don't exist  for a reason, it was mentioned more than once.

Comment: Historically, Stack Exchanged has avoided too many preferences.  While it was [recently noted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210473/182513) that more preferences would be forthcoming, going from none to 632 different options would be unlikely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The picture above sort of illustrates our reluctance here.

Customization of notifications is *hard to do well*.

- Giving enough control to address all your top users' individual needs (and remember that there will be a lot of diversity even *within* that group) almost always means most users, including some of the top ones, won't know what **many** of the settings even mean.
- Settings like that usually mean one of two things:

  - You've given up on getting your default selections right, and on making them adjust intelligently to different types of users, OR
  - You've spent a ton of time getting them right, but that meant making them *exactly* what you want, but you know darn well it's not what a lot of users actually do so you add crazy controls to placate the ones who tend to complain (loudly).  (Hi, Facebook!)

FWIW, I relate to your thinking here, and I regularly suggest plugging some problem much as you did above, but then someone always shows me a pic like that Facebook one, and I sigh and agree we have more work to do at making notifications smarter (rolling up more "noise" as users attract more of a certain kind of thing, etc.)

Side point:  The separation of Achievements and Inbox in the new Top Bar came out of exactly the kind of thinking you're doing here - we wanted most users to see even more feedback on upvotes, etc, but realized that Jon Skeet and others were already probably getting *way* more badge noise than made sense mixed in with other things, hence the clearer separations now.