# Reviewing high-rep users

Tags: discussion, review, high-rep-users

I recently started reviewing, and I noticed that I have a bias, especially with regards to close votes. I get that it's somewhat related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43104/hiding-reputation-and-encouraging-thinking-time-would-improve-the-quality-of-ans/43118#43118), but I find myself voting to close more often on questions asked by low rep users.

I understand that low rep users are simply *more likely* to ask bad questions. I can't deny, though, that seeing a "42.7k" next to a question I'm voting on feels a lot different than seeing a "16". It definitely factors into my decision-making process(one way or the other), and that doesn't feel right to me.

There's probably nothing technical that could be done about it, as it's quite obviously a human failing. I'm just curious if others find themselves feeling the same way, and what I can do to work on it.

Comment: As a self-described "low-rep user," please don't close-vote my question just because I'm not Jon Skeet.

Comment: Some high rep users get pretty sulky when you close their question and don't feel like contributing anymore.  So, yes, you'll risk that.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165932/it-feels-bad-to-be-on-the-receiving-end-of-a-closed-question

Comment: This is part of normal human reasoning and is a sign your brain is functioning correctly. I too will give something a second look if its from a high rep user (as they make mistakes less often) but try not to let it influence you more than that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't look at OP's name and reputation. Just look at question's content. And make your decision based on question's content/quality not based on OP's name & reputation. Because even Jon Skeet can also ask [non-constructive questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:22656%20closed:yes)

Comment: That was my first thought, too. Unfortunately, for most questions, the  name/rep block appears just left/down from dead center on my screen. I've tried not looking, but it's harder than it sounds.

Comment: @Geobits - There is no issue to look at reputation. Keep in mind: make your decision based on question's content not on reputation. And don't be afraid if any question reopen which is closed by your vote because mistakes are a part of human being.

Comment: Option to have it hidden if someone feels he is biased too easily would be nice. But can be done within the browser.